# Where to set API host schema in Swashbuckle?

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I'm trying to figure out how to fix an issue I have going on with Swagger displaying on our STAGE and PROD servers. I believe my issue is the fact that we have Load Balancer that uses HTTPS to get to but once you get there all the sites are served over HTTP. I believe that is the reason I'm getting

> Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings.

So I found the following on Swagger and I'm thinking I just need to set my Schema to HTTP but I'm not 100% sure where to make this change? Do I add it to the SwaggerConfig.cs file? 
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/api-host-and-base-path/

This is what I have in my SwaggerConfig.cs file:

```csharp
public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        //public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        public static void Register()
        {    
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.ApiKey("Api-Token")
                        .Description("API Key for accessing secure APIs")
                        .Name("Api-Token")
                        .In("header");

                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "WorkdayAPI");
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\WorkdayApi.XML",
                       System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));

                    // If you want the output Swagger docs to be indented properly, enable the "PrettyPrint" option.
                    c.PrettyPrint();

                })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {
                    // If your API supports ApiKey, you can override the default values.
                    // "apiKeyIn" can either be "query" or "header
                    c.EnableApiKeySupport("Api-Token", "header");
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: this should be valid `c.Schemes(new[] { "http", "https" });` _ _ _ _ what version of swashbuckle are you using?

Comment: I'm using Swashbuckle v5.6.0 and I tried both c.Schemes(new[] { "http", "https" }); and c.Schemes(new[] { "http" }). Neither of those worked. I would lover to get this to work so our business users could use it to test out the API but I've struggled through many hours and different combinations with no luck.

Comment: Have you enabled CORS on your api?